# Does sonarcloud.io support groovy?

Tags: gradle, groovy, sonarqube

I cannot get SonarQube to scan my .groovy files on sonarcloud.io. I added the following to my build.gradle:

```
sonarqube {
    properties {
        property 'sonar.host.url', 'https://sonarcloud.io'
        property 'sonar.organization', System.getenv('SONARQUBE_ORG')
        property 'sonar.login', System.getenv('SONARQUBE_LOGIN')
        property 'sonar.inclusions', '**/*.groovy,**/*.java'
    }
}
```

It reports indexing 5 files, but there are 0 lines of code in sonarcloud.io.

My source is in the 'sonarqube' branch at [here](https://bitbucket.org/double16/gradle-aws-ecr-plugin/src/bdde57fbffb4eae07dedf6eca9b962952203de8b/?at=sonarqube)

My sonar cloud project is at [here](https://sonarcloud.io/dashboard?id=com.patdouble%3Agradle-aws-ecr-plugin)

Here is a project that is scanning groovy, but I can't find the source code to determine how it is configured: [Link](https://sonarcloud.io/dashboard?id=org.xbib.groovy%3Agroovy-webapp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SonarCloud does not support Groovy analysis.

The project you found is an old one, not analyzed for more than a year. It's a left-over from the former version of the service (called SonarQube.com at that time) that had some sort of support for Groovy.

Comment: Is Groovy on the roadmap?

Comment: It's not for the moment.